# Display coordinates on a Google Map in Rails app

Tags: google-maps, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**Stage**:

In a Rails 3.2 application, suppose I have this model:

```
Point(id:integer, latitude:decimal, longitude:decimal, zoom:integer)
```

Using scaffold generator, it generates a form with 3 text fields like this:

```
<%= f.text_field :latitude %>
<%= f.text_field :longitude %>
<%= f.text_field :zoom %>
```

I really don't want to have this.
I prefer to have a Google Maps map and use it for set coordinates to the form and edit them.

I have seen that there are many solutions using Javascript, but if it is possible to avoid to use directly JS, it could be a good choice.

**Question**:

- Is the a gem that help to make this?
- What is good implementation of this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this without JavaScript.

What you need to do is:

- Add the google maps map to the page
- Add a click listener on the map

  - when the user clicks on the map (optionally place a marker and) get the lat/lng coordinates of the event, and use JS (maybe with the help of jQuery) to set your `:latitude` and `:longitude` form fields, as well as the current zoom level